# ListTile onTap animation

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, widget

I have this listtile view and I was planning to add a swipe feature for deleting and editing the details. However, the user won't know about this feature and might accidentally swipe and delete or edit an item unintentionally. To address this, I want to add a tap animation on the ListTile itself that provides clear instructions on how to use the swipe feature. Can anyone help me with this?[current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8a5C.jpg)

Something like this with a simple animation added to it.[looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WBef.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

With [flutter_slidable package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable), when the user slide the `ListTile`, it will display clickable textButtons, so it won't perform the function until the user clicks on the button.

For example label your textButtons like this:

```
final startActionButtons = <Widget> [
   SlidableAction(
      label: 'Edit',
      foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
      icon: Icons.edit,
      onPressed: () => editItem(),
   ),
];
final endActionButtons = <Widget> [
   SlidableAction(
      label: 'Delte',
      foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
      icon: Icons.delete,
      onPressed: () => deleteItem(),
   ),
];
```

Use the widget like this:

```
Slidable(
  key: ValueKey(0),
  //swipe right:
  startActionPane: ActionPane(
     motion: const ScrollMotion(),
     extentRatio: 0.2,
     children: startActionButtons,
     ),
  //swipe left:
  endActionPane: ActionPane(
     motion: const ScrollMotion(),
     extentRatio: 0.2,
     children: startActionButtons,
  ),
  child: ListTile(),
),
```

[image]

Comment: note that my example code is swipe left and right, different to the displayed gif demonstration